# php: Uninitialized string offset, how can I safely ignore it without doing it twice?

Tags: php, string

The following works:

```
if (!isset($mystring[$pos])) return false;
$char = $mystring[$pos];
```

So `isset()` tests that something that `$mystring[$pos]` returns and leaves the function if it is not set. But how do I get this magical something? If I do something like this:

```
$char = $mystring[$pos];
if (!isset($char)) return false;
```

Then I get the notification **Uninitialized string offset** and If I try to ignore that with `@$char = mystring[$pos];` then it also doesnt work. What is isset() receiving in this case?

Comment: `What is isset() receiving in this case?`...use `var_dump($char);` and you'll find out...

Comment: But really it makes no sense to test $char - it's too late by then  the problem of accessing a nonexistent array item has already passed, and suppressing the error is just hiding it instead of tackling it

Comment: @ADyson you're missing the point. The point is why does f(g(x)) work and y=g(x); f(y) does not even if it is logically the same.

Comment: `isset()` evaluates its arguments, in place, and stops as soon as an unset variable or index is encountered. It is **not** a normal function, it is a, so called, _"language construct"_.

Comment: `even if it is logically the same`...it's not logically the same. _That's_ the point. https://3v4l.org/UGQes, https://3v4l.org/2ABoA. In your second example, `$char` **is** set, it just doesn't have a useful value. What wasn't set was an index at $pos within the string.

Comment: Isset() checks if a variable is set, not if it is truthy. For that you can use empty().